# Linear Mappings and Ker

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $\{\vec{v_1},...,\vec{v_k}\}$ be a basis for a subspace $S$ of an $n$-dimensional vector space $V$. Prove that there exists a linear mapping $T:V\rightarrow V$ such that Ker$T=S$.

I reviewed the rank-nullity theorem and I am very lost with this proof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two hints:

- A basis for a subspace can be extended to a basis for the entire space.
- A linear transformation is specified once you know its values on a basis.